# on opening a data file to reading the lines included in that file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using the following code segment to partition a data file into two parts:

```
def shuffle_split(infilename, outfilename1, outfilename2):

    with open(infilename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    lines[-1] = lines[-1].rstrip('\n') + '\n'

    shuffle(lines)

    with open(outfilename1, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(lines[:90000])
    with open(outfilename2, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(lines[90000:])
    outfilename1.close()
    outfilename2.close()    
shuffle_split(data_file, training_file,validation_file)
```

Running this code segment cause the following error,

```
in shuffle_split
with open(infilename, 'r') as f:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

What's wrong with the way of opening the data_file for input?

Comment: Remove the first `with` statement and replace it with `infilename.readlines()`.

Comment: The error message says you fed a file handler which was already opened before shuffle_split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you're passing in as `infilename` is already a `file`, rather than a file's path name.